# How to make Application Insights stop logging "AspNetCoreEnvironment: Production"?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

Application Insights SDK for asp.net core is always inserting a custom dimension called "AspNetCoreEnvironment" with the value "Production" on my requests, dependencies, traces and etc...

How can I disable this?

Comment: I have added `builder.Services.RemoveAll<ITelemetryInitializer>();` line of code in my Program.cs file.Now I can see that `AspNetCoreEnvironment` is excluded from custom properties. Image [With Environment](https://i.imgur.com/Fs8MP2j.png) [Without Environment](https://i.imgur.com/hLBwX21.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we configure Application Insights for a WebApp, by default `AspNetCoreEnvironment`  can be seen under `Custom properties` of a `Request`,`Custom Event` and even on `Trace` Logs.

[image]

In `Program.cs` file, after

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

I have added the below line of code.

```cs
builder.Services.RemoveAll<ITelemetryInitializer>();
```

Now I can see that the `AspNetCoreEnvironment` property is excluded from the logs.

***Request:***
[image]

***Custom Event and Trace:***

[image]

Comment: did what I wanted but had several unexpected side effects... got me in the right path tough: I had to remove the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.TelemetryInitializers.AspNetCoreEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer`

Comment: The above code worked for me with my configurations.

Comment: is it possible to change the value of aspnetcoreenvironment,? i like to categories  the logs with dev,test,prod environment? thanks.

Comment: @saravanan049 -  Yes,You can change it.

Comment: @Harshitha could pls. give me few samples, or web reference to do this.

Comment: @saravanan049 - Can you post a new question with all your requirements in detail.

Comment: @Harshitha created a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918115/how-to-change-aspnetcoreenvironment-production-value-in-azure-application-ins .