# How to change "AspNetCoreEnvironment: Production" value in Azure Application Insights trace logs?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

we are about to migrate classic app insights of all 3 environment(dev, test and prod) to single workspace-based application insights, and noticed in application insights of all 3 environments(dev,test and prod) logs, the value of AspNetCoreEnvironment is production.
we dont know based on what and where it is inserting/coming from.

[image]

is there any way to change this AspNetCoreEnvironment value by code wise or azure protal side, so we can categized the logs based on the environments.

Comment: Have you deployed your app to Azure App service.If yes, you can set the value of `AspNetCoreEnvironment` in [Environment Variables](https://i.imgur.com/zfA8iY5.png) of the deployed app in Azure App Service.

Comment: If you run the application to run locally in Development Environment, you can set the value in [appsettings.Development.json](https://i.imgur.com/ViHQqyD.png) as Development.

Comment: @Harshitha just went through our app service environment variables. i couldnt find ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable declared. so that mean if we didnt declare ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, app insights will take production as a default value?

Comment: Yes,If you run the deployed app, by default the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is sets to `Production`.As I have mentioned above,you can set it accoring to your requirement.

Comment: How you are differentiating the Environments ?Do you have deployment slots ?

Comment: we maintaining separate library variable groups for each environment, and configured that in ymal file. so we aren't differentiating  using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

Comment: Once try by setting the value in Environment Variables as mentioned, it will work.

Comment: Let me know the update.

Comment: @Harshitha its working for me, after adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with respective value,  AspNetCoreEnvironment in logs are updating fine. thanks for your prompt support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256753/discussion-between-harshitha-and-saravanan049).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the value of `AspNetCoreEnvironment` of the deployed App is `Production`.

- You can see the 2 deployment slots here. I have deployed my sample App to Staging and Production.
- In Application Insights, you can see that even for the staging slot the Environment is shown as `Production`.

[image]

- If you want to change the value, it can be done from the Application Setting under  `Settings` => `Environment Variables`.
- Add the setting for the particular deployment slot where you want to change the value.

[image]

***Output after changing the value:***

[image]